# How do I get those to fold on to itself?

Tags: edit-mode, mirror

I'm trying to fold this mesh from it's z axis so that it can fit into another mesh.  However, I'm not sure how I can do this.  This is my mesh.

[image]

I want to rotate it on the Z-Axis in the center so it'll fold into a flat half like a piece of paper.

My attempt at folding it using the x mirror in edit mode.  Some vertices are not following the rotation:

[image]

I just want to fold this so that I can attach the outter points to this mesh:

[image]

What's the best way I can fold this?  If it's with the X mirror how come some points are not following my rotation?

Comment: I don't think I understood your goal ... so just speaking to weirdly moving vertices - check Face Orientation (overlay).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `Curve Object`
2. Edit the `Curve Object` to have a sort of Arc shape
3. Apply Transforms of the `Curve Object`
4. Add `Curve Modifier` to your `Mesh`
5. set the `object` to be your curve:
   [image]
6. Now, play around with the deform axis in the modifier,
   the location of your mesh and its scale to find the best
7. Ready!! I was able to curve this mesh with the steps:
   [image]
8. You can add subdiv, either smooth modifiers to smooth out your mesh after curving